# How to generate Rankings in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complex scenario in Mysql. My table structure and data looks like below:

```
Field_a   Field_b   Field_c   Total    Rank
-------   -------   -------   -----    ----
1.2       1.1       3.9       6.2      1
1.2         0         0       1.2      4
1.2       1.1         0       3.3      3
1.2         0       3.9       5.1      2
1.2         0       3.9       5.1      2
1.2         0         0       1.2      4
```

The field and "Total" and "Rank" don't exist and i have to generate them while querying into database. Is there any ways to retrieve Rank in mysql?

Regards
Dolendra

Comment: stored procedure to make the ranks so u dont have to query it

Answer (score 2):

```
set @N:=0;
select *,@N:=@N+1 as Rank from
(
select Field_a ,  Field_b ,  Field_c, Field_a  + Field_b +  Field_c  as total 
from table
) as t
order by total desc
```

Comment: Isn't this a `row_number()` equivilent, rather than a `rank()` or `dense_rank()` equivilent? The op wants ranks `1,2,2,3,4,4` where as this would seem to return `1,2,3,4,5,6`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.Field_a + t1.Field_b + t1.Field_c AS total, t2.rank FROM table5 t1
  JOIN (SELECT total, @r:= @r + 1 rank FROM (SELECT Field_a + Field_b + Field_c AS total FROM table5 GROUP BY total DESC) t1, (SELECT @r:=0) t2 ORDER BY total DESC) t2
    ON t1.Field_a + t1.Field_b + t1.Field_c = t2.total
```

Comment: +1 : Same methodolody as another answer here, with one key difference.  It gives the results the OP asked for ;)

Comment: @Dems: right in this case order of rows is preserved by using join with derived rank table.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT Field_a, Field_b, Field_c, 
       IF((Field_a + Field_b + Field_c) <> @var_total_prev, 
           (@var_rank:= @var_rank + 1), 
            @var_rank) AS rank,
       (@var_total_prev := (Field_a + Field_b + Field_c)) AS total
FROM my_table a,(SELECT @var_rank := 0, @var_total_prev := 0) r
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Everything's alright until we change *order by total* to *order by field_a**,**order by field_b*

Comment: ya @Devart's answer will preserver the same order which you have mentioned in question. The only difference is that I am not using sub-query so performance wise its better.